# MATLAB plot square marker showing as cross

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, marker

I am having a problem with the plot function. in the documentation an 's' after the colour label in plot should represent a square. it comes up as a cross (see line 1268 in the image below.

i want the marker to display a square.

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is plotting a square marker, but you're using a `LineWidth` of 6 and since MATLAB uses [butt line caps](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/linecaps.htm), this makes it appear like a cross like you've shown. If we increase the `MarkerSize` we can really see what's happening.

```
plot(1,1,'rs', 'MarkerSize', 100, 'LineWidth', 6)
```

[image]

And if we zoom in, we'll see the notches in the corners.

[image]

Your options are to either increase the `MarkerSize` if you really want to increase the `LineWidth` or not use such a large `LineWidth`.

```
plot(1, 1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]